# do t.test in R by column indexing and using apply or loop

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics, apply

is there a way to do multiple t test in R by using a column as a index?
I would like to do a t test on x$viability by indexing x$Cross to 1F. Thus 1M, 2M, etc are compared to 1F. I know I can do this individually but is there a way to do a loop or apply on this?
here is the data below

```
X;

Cross   Rep Block   Viability
1F  1   1   0.8333333
1F  2   1   0.8333333
1F  3   1   0.8
1M  1   1   0.8333333
1M  2   1   0.8666667
1M  3   1   1
2M  1   1   0.9333333
2M  2   1   0.8666667
2M  3   1   0.8333333
3M  1   1   0.9333333
3M  2   1   0.9
3M  3   1   0.9
4M  1   1   0.8333333
4M  2   1   0.9666667
4M  3   1   0.9333333
5M  1   1   0.9666667
5M  2   1   0.9666667
5M  3   1   0.9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use any of the group by operations

```
library(data.table)
setDT(X)[, t.test(Viability)$p.value, by = Cross]
#    Cross           V1
#1:    1F 0.0001825647
#2:    1M 0.0031854465
#3:    2M 0.0011197313
#4:    3M 0.0001486875
#5:    4M 0.0019277856
#6:    5M 0.0005531744
```

We can do `pairwise.t.test` for the updated question

```
res <- with(X, pairwise.t.test(Viability, Cross))
res$p.value
#           1F 1M 2M 3M 4M
# 1M 1.0000000 NA NA NA NA
# 2M 1.0000000  1 NA NA NA
# 3M 0.9260886  1  1 NA NA
# 4M 0.9260886  1  1  1 NA
# 5M 0.2501720  1  1  1  1
```

---

If we need to get the same result as individual comparison, we have to change the `p.adj`, `paired`, `pool.sd` etc in `pairwise.t.test`

With individual comparison,

```
t.test(X$Viability[X$Cross=='1F'], 
          X$Viability[X$Cross=='1M'])$p.value
 #[1] 0.2636938
```

With `pairwise.t.test`

```
with(X, pairwise.t.test(Viability, Cross, p.adj='none', 
         paired=FALSE, pool.sd=FALSE))$p.value
#                1F        1M        2M        3M        4M
#1M 0.263693796        NA        NA        NA        NA
#...
```

NOTE: There is still some rounding difference (if it is okay)

Comment: Sorry Akrun that works, not for what I need, but see new edits. I wasn't clear enough based on this answer.

Comment: @ Akrun why do I get different p values when using your method vs doing them individually? I.E. when I take all three 1F values (Viability) and compare to all 1M values. I get using this etDT(Nicdata)[, pairwise.t.test(Viability, Cross, p.adj = "none", paired = FALSE)] a p value of 0.102, but when I do a normal t.test I get p-value = 0.2099.

Comment: @Genetics There is an adjustment for multiple  comparisons

Comment: @ akrun, I see that, but didnt I turn this off p.adj = "none"?

Comment: @Genetics I think the `pool.sd` is creating the difference.  Please check my update.

Comment: This works, thanks alot. The rounding thing at this point is due to a simple two sample t test vs Welch's t test. This is now explainable. Cheers